# New jobs emails are either not honoring preferences or are doing so poorly

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, email

I have been getting completely random Job emails for the last few months. Here is what I get when I set my preferences to Clojure, security,  and Linux kernel.

[image]

This is indistinguishable from random spam. It would be preferable not to send anything if there are no close matches.

---- UPDATE -----

This was marked "fixed" even though it is clearly not fixed. here is another example from this morning:

[image: more random-spam job emails matching "clojure"]

Comment: I've noticed the same thing with the Jobs ads that are supposed to be targeting me in the sidebar of the home page. I suspect it's because the person who created the job listing just spammed tags and/or keywords. There is no other explanation for why I see so many Python and JavaScript jobs, despite never having answered a question in either one of those languages.

Comment: I do hope they work on tag proliferation. I'm also concerned they are showing things for the sake of showing something even when no actual matches exist. Hopefully someone here can tell which of these (or both) is going on.

Comment: I'm confident something is actually broken.  The only tag I had subscribed to was "internet radio".  The stuff I ended up with was completely random, and not related at all.  I unsubscribed... I wasn't really looking for a job anyway.

Comment: I'm looking into this now.

Comment: @Brad in your case you're doing a search for 'internet radio' without any quotes. We give additional weight to the query if it contains the literal term 'internet radio' but jobs also receive weight if they contain either individual term. When it comes to alerts; once you've received all the jobs with the literal term you'll start to receive the ones that weren't such great matches. I'd suggest using a quoted string instead: "internet radio". Or if there are tags that match they tend to be higher quality matches.

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things at work here:

First your search is a full text search which means if the word "Clojure" is found *anywhere* in the job at all it'll be picked up. If you want to be more stringent about the things that it matches you can perform a tag search by using the 'Tech you like' part of the filter pane:

[image: Tech you like]

Secondly we have a feature called 'auto-targeting' that uses some ML to determine a set of tags that we think would be appropriate for a job and it appears to have a bug determining when `clojure` should be applied. I've changed the search algorithm to exclude this field for now (it's generally secondary to other things anyway) and will push to production shortly.

The above should eliminate those jobs from your alerts, but it's worth noting we're also working out the threshold at which a job is considered not useful. That's a little way off (we need to collect more data and then understand how it affects apply rates, etc.) but is being thought about.

Comment: I do have it set as a tag search, and just wanted to let you know that this is not at all fixed. I solved it by blocking all jobs email. And added a picture of today's email to the question.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt I beg to differ. The email that you received there is for the keyword "clojure" which is picked up in the body of that job

Comment: That is picked up in [this keyword search](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?q=Clojure&r=True&j=permanent) but not [this tag search](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs?sort=i&tl=Clojure&r=true&j=permanent)